# How to use boolean statements and return

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to create a piece of code which will;

return true if given an int n, which is with in 10 of 100 or 200.

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
class nearHundred{
public boolean nearHundred(int n){



    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    n = input.nextInt();

    if(10>=Math.abs(100-n) || 10>=Math.abs(200-n)){
        return true;
    }


    return false;
    }
}
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: What do you mean "gone wrong"? What is/isn't the program doing?

Comment: It looks right to me. Maybr you are messing up by overwriting the variable n with your nextint

Comment: Why do you pass n into the method? it is just clobbered on the method's second statement.

Comment: MQ87 I think you are correct, well now I have another problem; I am unable to even run the code for some reason, when I press the run button another piece of code from a different class runs instead/

Comment: Nelios what should I put as the method parameter above, instead of int n

"...nearHundred(int n){.."

Comment: First you have to make up your mind what the method _does_.  Do you want a method that reads a number from your file and tests whether that number meets your condition, or do you want a method that takes a number as a parameter and tests that number?  If you want the first one, get rid of the parameter.  If you want the second, get rid of the line that calls `nextInt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments it looks like your main method is misplaced, wherever it is I hope it exists only once in a project. Call your class from that main() method, for example -

```
new nearHundred().nearHundred(100); // a call from main method
```

Now coming to your code there are several things to correct here. Your method should not take care about Scanner, its job is to take input and check for the logic.

For example;

```
public class Utils {
  public static boolean isNearToHundered(int num) {
      return Math.abs(num-100)<=10 || Math.abs(num-200)<=10;
  }
}
```

Give the responsibility to main method for parsing the input, this is how it should work.

Now since I made method `static`, you can call like

```
Utils.isNearToHundred(105); // TRUE
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is how the method should look:

```
    public void mainMethod() {
     Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in); 
     int val=input.nextInt();
     boolean nearHundredBoolean=nearHundred(val);
     //do something with nearHundredBoolean....


   //Same logic, but passes the input to the method nearHundred
  public boolean nearHundred(int n) {
   if(Math.abs(100-n)<=10 || Math.abs(200-n)<=10)
      return true;
       else return false; 
       }
```

You should pass the value of the scanner input into this method's parameter requirement, instead of not using the parameter n in your current method. If there is a problem, it may be due to the 'input.nextInt()' method that overwrites the value of the parameter n.